# Checkstyle Multiline regex for specific methods

Tags: java, regex, multiline, checkstyle

I'm working on java checkstyle configuration in Eclipse. I need to add warning for all public methods that don't consist specific code in the first line. Example:

```
public void doA(){
    blabla();
    //some code
}

public String doB(int i){
    blabla();
    //some code
}

public Boolean doC(String str){
    //some code
}
```

What I want from checkstyle is to mark the line or report error when there is method that has public modifier and doesn't start with calling  blabla() method. I tried to make some multiline regexp strings with /n as a newline but so far no success.

edit: so far I tried this but without success:

```
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="format" value="(public)(\\s+)((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))(\\s+)((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))(\\(.*\\))(\\{)(/n)(blablabla)"/>
    <property name="message" value="Public method should have blablabla."/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Pattern.MULTILINE directive in the search pattern: `"(?m)...\\s*..."`. This applies the pattern across lines.

Use Pattern.DOTALL directive in the search pattern: `"(?s)...\\s*..."`. This captures '\n`with a`.`.

Use it combined: `"(?ms)..."`.

Comment: Thanks for an answer but how I should use it in the checkstyle xml? So far I tried one solution but doesn't work. I added it to original post above.

Comment: This is not going to work, because you need a regex which matches when `blabla();` is *not* present. This called a "negative lookahead assertion". I fiddled with my Checkstyle for a while and could not get it to accept the `(?!...)` construct, even though a hand-coded java.util.regex pattern matcher worked fine. You may end up having to write a custom check.

Comment: @Thomas: Personally I would rename blabla, and make a `@Deprecated` blabla. But would have thought that something like `"(?ms)\npublic[^\n{]+\\s*{(?!\\bblabla\\().)*}\n\n"` *(errorneous, to-do)* would work.